# How to get the Form.DesktopBounds from before the window was minimized or maximized

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to save and restore the state of a WinForms [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx), more specifically the [DesktopBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.desktopbounds.aspx) and the [WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx).

However, when the WindowState is not normal (i.e. minimized or maximized) then I would like to save the *previous* value of DesktopBounds, when the Form was still in a normal state.

Obviously, windows remembers this previous state somewhere, because clicking the maximize button twice restores the original position and size of the form. How do I read this original state?

**EDIT**: Some similar SO questions:

- [How to make a form remember its Bounds and WindowState (Taking dual monitor setups into account)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495380/c-how-to-make-a-form-remember-its-bounds-and-windowstate-taking-dual-monitor-s).
- [How to record window position in WinForms application settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105932/how-to-record-window-position-in-winforms-application-settings).
- [Restoring Window Size/Position With Multiple Monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937298/restoring-window-size-position-with-multiple-monitors).
- [Save and Restore Form Position and Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92540/save-and-restore-form-position-and-size).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check [RestoreBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.restorebounds.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks! I have added an annotation to the MSDN documentation of DesktopBounds, suggesting that they add a "see also" reference to RestoreBounds.